# Lockless memory buffer protection

Tags: c++, multithreading, lockless

While using a lockless queue implementation to store the pointers to a set of buffers that are preallocated, I found that some buffers are still being written by one thread while the other thread starts using it. I have already protected the buffer writes and reads with memory barriers but it seems not to work.

Thread 1 loop:

```
auto b=queue.AcquireBuffer();

for (int x=0;x<BUF_SIZE;x++)
{
    b->GetData()[x]=-999999999990;          // A
}
atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)   // edit: still does not work
high_resolution_clock::time_point tp=high_resolution_clock::now();
b->GetData()[1]=1+time_diff(tp,tp_normal);  // B

atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
queue.PushBuffer(b);
```

Thread 2 loop:

```
auto bb=queue.Peak();

atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);

if ((bb[0])->GetData()[1] < 0) {
    std::cout<<"fail"<<endl;
    ready=true;
    while (1) {}
}

queue.Pop();
```

I get "fail" as output after sometime which means that Thread 2 sees unordered execution of A and B blocks. I want these things to happen in order. How can I fix it? (Assume that time_diff always returns a positive number)

The queue source: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PFBzMPPF

Entire source: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8gY3VVJJr1IMktobnhYelBva2c/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: You don't show the code for the `queue` functions, which is, of course, the critical part.  (Your code doesn't do anything to ensure ordering between A and B.)

Comment: @JamesKanze See the edits above, I've also added the queue source. I used the barrier at multiple places to no avail.

Comment: I should also mention that I tested the queue thoroughly for primitive values and it worked well the queue implemention is based up on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43510/Lock-Free-Single-Producer-Single-Consumer-Circular#heading_how_it_works

Comment: Your `Peak` function, I assume, measures the top of the queue? Or did you mean `Peek`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson it returns the pointer on top of the queue (whats to be removed on the next pop())

Comment: You need thread synchronization, but you are using memory synchronization. These are different things.

Comment: chris, yes but I do not want to use mutex locks here it works well with mutexes but that defeats the use of a lockless queue

Comment: So, in other words, your function should be "peek" (look inside somwhere, rather than peak which is the highest point of something [a curve, mountain range, etc] - using correct terminology is useful for other people reading your code). What code does `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` actually generate? What compiler is it?

Comment: True that. I am not a native speaker. Im using g++ currently

Comment: I just took a quick glance at the code for the queue, but I don't see any way that it could possibly be correct.

Comment: it is single consumer- single producer. its quite bold to say what i got from codeproject is in no way correct, could you point out why?